# Issues with bind_rows() from dplyr about numeric and character

Tags: r, list, bind, lapply, rbind

I have this code

> ```
> setwd("F:/2017_FALL/RETAILING/DB")
>   files <- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx")
>   dta_rtl_smalla <- lapply(files, read_excel) %>% 
>   dplyr::bind_rows()
> ```

I would like to make one file from multiple data(.xlsx) in my directory.
However, there is an issue about a certain column.
This is the message.

> Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) :    Column `A` can't be converted from
>   character to numeric In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use
>   warnings() to see the first 50)

I've searched the similar problem on the internet, while those are about 'bind_rows' functions between just two samples.

How do I adjust my code with the list.file and lapply function to resolve the problem....?..

Comment: Is there only a single column or multiple column problem?   Try to read one dataset and then use the `class` of the columns in `colClasses` so that there will be consistency in class.   It is better to look why one column is `character` while it should be numeric.  Is it because of some weird characters